# Angular 13: Dynamic Html with data binding

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular13

My Requirement is to bind data to dynamically added HTML content.
for i.e,

**`app.component.html`**

```html
<div>
    <p> {{data.name}} </p>
    <div class="contact" [innerHTML]="htmlContent | safe: 'html'"></div>
<div>
```

I have created a safe pipe to bind html content.

**`app.component.ts`**

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponet {
    data = {
        name: 'sample',
        mobile: '9999988888',
        email: 'temp@mail.com'
    };
    htmlContent = '';

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getDynamicContent();
    }

    // api call to get dynamic content 
    getDynamicContent() {
        this.htmlContent = `<p class="email">Email: {{data.email}}</p>
            <br><p class="mobile">Mobile: {{data.mobile}}</p>`;
    }
}
```

this is just simple example of my requirements the actual thing is little bit complex. **attaching the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-25dpdc) URL for example.**

Comment: What is the problem you see? What do you see in your console? Where did you get the safe pipe from? Angular has none pre-defined - for good reasons.

Comment: I have created the custom pipe. check the stackblitz demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:
You will add html content after data is loaded.

Then just replace this:

```
this.htmlContent = `<p class="email">Email: {{data.email}}</p>
            <br><p class="mobile">Mobile: {{data.mobile}}</p>`;
```

with:

```
this.htmlContent = `<p class="email">Email: ${this.data.email}</p>
        <br><p class="mobile">Mobile: ${this.data.mobile}</p>`;
```

If you are adding content using this.htmlContent then you don't need to use data-binding because you can use the feature of javascript template literals.